# Can an aliased query use a contain clause?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, contains

I use a union to join two datasets and then the following query to setup for pagination correctly

```
$paginationQuery = $this->find('all')
    ->contain(['EmailAddresses' => [
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'queryBuilder' => function($q) {
                  return $q->where(['Members__id' => 'EmailAddresses.member_id']);
                 }
        ]])
        ->select( $selectMainUnion )
        ->from([$this->getAlias() => $query])
        ->order(['Members__last_name' => 'ASC', 'Members__first_name' => 'ASC']);
```

I have also tried

```
$paginationQuery = $this->find('all')
        ->contain(['EmailAddresses'])
        ->select( $selectMainUnion )
        ->from([$this->getAlias() => $query])
        ->order(['Members__last_name' => 'ASC', 'Members__first_name' => 'ASC']);
```

and tried
    $query->loadInto($query, ['EmailAddresses']); where $query is the result of the union.

Neither of these result in email addresses added to $paginationQuery.

Is there a way to do this?

Adding to clarify the code

```
$selectMain =['Members.id',
    'Members.member_type',
    'Members.first_name',
    'Members.middle_name',
    'Members.last_name',
    'Members.suffix',
    'Members.date_joined'];

foreach($selectMain as $select) {
    $selectMainUnion[] = str_replace('.', '__', $select);
}

$this->hasMany('EmailAddresses', [
   'foreignKey' => 'member_id',
   'dependent' => true,
]);
```

Looking at the SQL in DebugKit SQL Log, there is no reference to the EmailAddresses table.

Comment: I think it should work as long as the query selects the required primary/foreign key fields for the association. What does your association configuration and `$selectMainUnion` look like?

Comment: @ndm Added code above to answer your question.

Comment: I see, aliasing the fields is probably what causes the problem. I guess you're not changing the format of the selected fields for the union query (`$query`)? If you debug `$query->sql()` it will probably show something like `SELECT Members.Members__id AS "Members__Members__id"`?

Comment: Sorry, I ment debugging `$paginationQuery`!

Comment: @ndm I've changed my queryBuilder function to use Members__Members__id. However, it appears the the contain clause is ignored, there is no use of the EmailAddresses table in SQL code for $paginationQuery.

Comment: That's not what I intended to say, I was just asking whether your query produces that in the select list?, as that is what would prevent the associated data to be injected. `hasMany` associations are retrieved in separate queries, hence no reference in that query.

Comment: @ndm Yes the query does produce that in the select list. As an update, I just tried adding 'strategy' => 'subquery' to the contain clause and it is now involving the EmailAddresses table. So that seems a good step forward. Errors now that it can't find Members.id in the field list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally containments do work fine irrespective of the queries `FROM` clause, whether that's a table or a subquery should be irrelevant. The requirement for this to work however is that the required primary and/or foreign key fields are being selected, and that they are in the correct format.

By default CakePHP's ORM queries automatically alias selected fields, ie they are being selected like `Alias.field AS Alias__field`. So when `Alias` is a subquery, then `Alias.field` doesn't exist, you'd have to select `Alias.Alias__field` instead. So with the automatic aliases, your select of `Members__id` would be transformed to `Members.Members__id AS Members__Members__id`, and `Members__Members__id` is not something the ORM understands, it would end up as `Members__id` in your entities, where the eager loader would expect `id` instead, ie the name of the primary key which is used to inject the results of the queried `hasMany` associated records (this happens in a separate query), your custom `queryBuilder` won't help with that, as the injecting happens afterwards on PHP level.

Long story short, to fix the problem, you can either change how the fields of the union queries are selected, ie ensure that they are not selected with aliases, that way the pagination query fields do not need to be changed at all:

```
$fields = $table->getSchema()->columns();
$fields = array_combine($fields, $fields);

$query->select($fields);
```

This will create a list of fields in the format of `['id' => 'id', ...]`, looks a bit whacky, but it works (as long as there's no ambiguity because of joined tables for example), the SQL would be like `id AS id`, so your pagination query can then simply reference the fields like `Members.id`.

Another way would be to select the aliases of the subquery, ie not just select `Member__id`, which the ORM turns into `Member__Member__id` when it applies automatic aliasing, but use `Members.Member__id`, like:

```
[
    'Member__id' => 'Members.Member__id',
    // ...
]
```

That way no automatic aliasing takes place, on SQL level it would select the field like `Members.Member__id AS Member__id`, and the field would end up as `id` in your entities, which the eager loader would find and could use for injecting the associated records.